# Why does my .cshtml page need to define content?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Let's say I have the following structure in my ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

- Items

  - Index.cshtml
- Categories
- Shared

  - _Index.cshtml
  - _Site.cshtml
  - Index.cshtml

Both `Index.cshtml` files use `_Index.cshtml` as the layout page and `_Index` is nested within the `_Site` layout.

`Items/Index` implements the optional sections defined in `_Index`. `Shared/Index` is empty.

The `Items/Index` view works fine. Since Categories doesn't have an Index, it uses the one in the Shared folder. This does not work.

It throws the error

> The "RenderBody" method has not been called for layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Index.cshtml".

If `_Site` calls `RenderBody`, and `_Index` inherits from `_Site`, doesn't the content in `_Index` satisfy the required `RenderBody` call and `Shared/Index.cshtml` can be blank?

The reason I ask is because I have an ASP.NET MVC 1 application  that implemented this structure using Master pages and it worked fine, but converting it to MVC 3 with Razor is causing this issue.

Here is the basic outline of what I'm describing:

_Site.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
// head
<body>
  @RenderBody()
</body>
```

_Index.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Site.cshtml";
}

<div id="sub-menu">
  // Markup
</div>

// More markup

@RenderSection("SectionOne", required: false)

@RenderSection("SectionTwo", required: false)
```

Items/Index.cshtml (Working)

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Index.cshtml";
}

@section SectionOne {
  // Markup
}
```

Shared/Index.cshtml (RenderBody error)

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Index.cshtml";
}

// Rest of this file is empty
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure i follow you completely, but *ALL* layout pages have to have a `RenderBody()`, even if they're nested.  `RenderBody()` renders the content for the "child".  When you have nested layout pages the nested layout is the child of the parent, and it's output must be rendered in the RenderBody.  Likewise, the child of the child has to render it's body into the middle page.

To put it another way, anything that's not in a @section is considered the "body".  So, _Index.cshtml needs to render it's body (Index.cshtml) and _Site.html has to render it's body (_Index.cshtml).  It goes up the chain.

EDIT:

It appears that a layout has to render at least one section, be it with a `RenderBody()` or a `RenderSection()`.  While it may be true that the sections are optional, rendering at least one section is not.  Either add an empty section to your Index.cshtml or add a RenderBody() to your _Index.cshtml.

Comment: My _Index.cshtml does not call @RenderBody though. _Index just implements the sections from _Site, and defines a few new ones. Then Item/Index implements a few of the _Index sections. That's it.

Comment: @Brandon - Perhaps it would help if you included some basic cshtml code illustrating, because I just don't understand what you're describing.

Comment: updated question. Maybe I'm not implementing nested pages correctly, but thats basically the structure of it.

Comment: @Brandon - Well, it looks like there must be at least one rendered section, be it a body or a section.  You could just include an empty section in your other index.

Comment: that is what I've done. I'm just wondering why I would be forced to implement an optional section in this case. If it's just because I have no Body and it wants something to render, add that to your answer and I'll accept. Thanks.

Comment: @Brandon - the other option is to add a `RenderBody()` to your _Index.cshtml.  It will just render nothing.